# Laravel API send array of files from vue js

Tags: file-upload, vuejs2, laravel-8

Hello I have  a problem with sending img files to API

```
e.target.files.forEach(file => {
     this.images[id]= file;
});

async handleFormSubmit(){
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('images[]',this.images);
    await this.setCreatePost(data)
}
```

When I console.log file i get:

```
lastModified: 1637855593567
lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 25 2021 16:53:13 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
name: "elena-putina-WuSzNJpys_4-unsplash.jpg"
size: 1027854
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

and when I console.log formData i get:

```
data: Array(1)
0: "[object File]"
length: 1
```

and when I try to stringify file i get:

```
data: ['[{}]']
```

and when I decode it at API I get empty object.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `handleSubmitForm()` i was appending like this: `data.append('images[]',this.images);`

And it needs to be appended like this:

```
this.images.forEach((image) => {
            data.append('images[]', image);
        });
```

And at Laravel I can do for each loop like this:
(before it didn't work)

```
foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
   $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
   $image_name = time().'_'.$image_name;
   $image->move(storage_path('images'), $image_name);
}
```